# Удалить оба равных между собой Kotlin bean, классов по значению

Tags: android, kotlin, list

Есть два List, есть Kotlin bean, и в между собой в два List, если есть похожие между собой значения по `fullTime`, удалить в обоих List.

```kotlin
class Time(
    var fullTime: String,
    var date: Calendar,
    var hour: Int,
    var minute: Int,
    var inMillis: Long,
    var day: Int
)
```

Например [1,3,5,6] и есть второй лист, там значения [3]
И получается нужно получить список в виде [1,5,6]

Comment: Могут ли в одном списке быть несколько объектов Time с одинаковыми fullTime?

Answer (score 0):

Определим `equals` и `hashCode` для класса `Time` следующим образом:

```kotlin
class Time(
    var fullTime: String,
    ...
) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false
        return fullTime == (other as Time).fullTime
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return fullTime.hashCode()
    }
}
```

После чего мы можем складывать объекты класса `Time` не только в `List`, но и в `Set`, и выполнить операцию `minus`:

```kotlin
val set1 = list1.toSet() // [1, 3, 5, 6]
val set2 = list2.toSet() // [3, 4]
val result = set1.minus(set2) // => [1, 5, 6]
```

Метод `minus` реализует [разность множеств](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2).

Answer (score 0):

Есть два списка:

```kotlin
val list1: List<Time> // [1, 3, 5, 6]
val list2: List<Time> // [3, 4]
```

Из второго списка сделаем сет значений `fullTime`:

```kotlin
val set2 = list2.map { it.fullTime }.toSet()
```

После чего воспользуемся методом `filter`:

```kotlin
val result = list1.filter { it.fullTime !in set2 } // => [1, 5, 6]
```